# Problem with Background image scrolling up and down?

Tags: css, background-image

While moving the page up and down the background image is not getting scroll.I need to scroll the image while moving the page up and down.

```
<div  class=" vc_custom_1543236867694 ">    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h4 class="headingMargin45"><span class="successful">Successful</span> <span class="s_span_p"><strong>Story</strong></span><i>&nbsp;</i></h4>
    </div>  
        <div class="simple-text">
                    "Just have to say a very caring dentist who excels in reassuring their patients and gives excellent service, explains what they are doing every step of the way. The best dentist I have ever seen."    
        </div>
 </div>
```

I have written for scrolling but it didn't work.Here is the code for css

```
.vc_custom_1543236867694{
background-size: initial;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 50% 0 !important;
animation: bg-slides 50s linear infinite;   
}
@-moz-keyframes bg-slides{
from { transform: translateX(0); }
to { transform: translateY(-5%); }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes bg-slides {
from { transform: translateX(0); }
to { transform: translateY(-5%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bg-slide {
from { transform: translateX(0); }
to { transform: translateY(-5%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes bg-slide{
from { transform: translateX(0); }
to { transform: translateY(-5%); }
}
.vc_custom_1542787903073{
background-size: initial;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 50% 0 !important;
animation: bg-slide 50s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a working example of what you are trying to achieve? Also, keep your code simple without any extra classes (It seems that you are editing on a `Visual Composer` element on `WordPress`)

Comment: Are you trying to implement a parallax effect? (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp)

Comment: @Elharony i was trying in this format http://reddysdental.co.nz/ in this website scrolling the pager down we can see testimonials and request a dental cote if we scroll the page those background images are scrolling in the same way i need the background image to be scrolled

Comment: @Arjan i have written some text on background image  so if i move the page up or down the background image should scroll and the text should remain same.Only the image need to be scrolled

Comment: Yes its wordpress only but whant to write css for scrolling background image

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether it's what you need to achieve or not, but it seems like a `Parallax` effect!

Here's a simple example:

```css
body {
  height: 600px
}
section {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/11/22/23/57/london-3833039_960_720.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
section .content {
  padding: 50px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="content">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text</div>
</section>
```

If it's not what you are looking for, try to clarify your question more! :)

Comment: reddysdental.co.nz in this url we can find testimonials in the home page in the same page i need the scrolling effect.

Answer (score 0):

To make the image fixed on the page and scroll, use the below:

`background-attachment: fixed;`